# how to use codeigniter CLI

Tags: codeigniter, command-line-interface

i'm a newbie in using codeigniter cli
i'm using xampp and my project located in

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\mycli\
```

my code is like this

```
public function myfunction($to = "WORLD"){
 echo "HELLO {$to}!".PHP_EOL;
}
```

i trying to use this cmd line base on codeigniter tutorial on cli

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\my_cli\index.php mycontroller myfunction "test"
```

but it doesn't work it just showing index.php file. i also using htacess to remove the index.php in the url.

Comment: Did you name your controller mycontroller.php and inside that controller `class Mycontroller extends CI_Controller` ?? Check the capitalization of both - file name and class declaration. And also, you are missinf ! after {$to}

Comment: yes my controller is mycotroller.php and the class Mycontroller extends CI_Controller. It just keeping opening the index.php 
is there i need to config to use the CLI?? tnxs

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
cd /path/to/project
php index.php mycontroller myfunction test
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can execute `php index.php controller action`

or you can call it thorough the http protocol

```
wget http://example.com/example/test/bar/


curl http://example.com/example/test/bar/
```

Reference: http://mildcoder.com/handling-codeigniter-in-cli-and-cron-jobs/

Answer (score 0):

step1: cmd

step2: check your cmd ->

```
"php -V"


if step2 got error: your php.exe is not in your sys's path{
  step3: 
c:\xampp\php\php c:\xampp\htdocs\my_cli\index.php mycontroller myfunction "test"
}
if step2 show like this: php 5.3.6 ...............{
  step3 is:
php c:\xampp\htdocs\my_cli\index.php mycontroller myfunction "test"
}
```